# Sequel Pro connection to Mysql 8.0 server doesn't list database

Tags: mysql, centos8

I'm setting up Mysql 8.0 on my Centos 8 server. I've followed a guide for setting up Mysql, and although it's for the previous Centos version, installation was successful. However, when I connect to my DB through Sequel Pro, I can add a new database, but it isn't listed afterwards? Sequel Pro also continuously displays as connecting even though I'm connected?

When I run: `mysqladmin -u root -p version` and provide my password, I do indeed se that the DB is up, and running `sudo systemctl status mysqld` shows as **Active (running)**, but I'm not sure why by DB isn't listed in Sequel Pro?

[image: db]

If I try to re-add the DB, it says it already exists, but isn't showing up...

[image: server]